# To get remote machine (desktop or server) system configuration and utilization parameters using Java

Tags: java, command-line

Is it possible to connect to remote machine (using administrative privilege) by java and get the following machine details

1. IP
2. CPU Utilization
3. HDD capacity
4. RAM and
5. Find directory structure .

Is there any way to use command line in java to achieve the same?

Comment: Has it to be java? Because you invoke it from the command-line. For what operating system(s)?

Comment: Can be any OS solaris,Windows or linux

Answer (score 2):

Your information you request is typically embedded in SNMP.

For more information abount SNMP look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base

There are various SNMP implementations of SNMP in Java, one of the more commonly used is [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/)

Enjoy !